# How to organize Poly and create Node

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, linked-list

In this class Polynomial takes in a list of tuples like such >> [(1,2),(3,1),(2,3),(2,2)]

What I need to do for this specific part is take in a list of tuples and then the insert function and **init** functions should be able to organize the data in ascending order based on exponents by creating nodes in the Node class.

**Right now my code is returning this:**

```
>>> p = Poly([(1,0),(2,2),(1,1),(3,4)])

>>> print(p)

3x^4Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 5, line 1
builtins.TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

*It is meant to be a linked list and I am not allowed organizing the list before hand or converting it into a dictionary or any other form. It should be organized from the insert and **init** function.*

```
class Poly:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, coef, power, _next):
            self._coef = coef   #coefficient from tuple first number
            self._power = power # exponent from tuple second number
            self._next = None
        def __repr__(self):
            pass
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self._head = None
        for i in lst:
            coefficient = i[0]
            exponent = i[1]
            self._head = self.Node(coefficient, expo, self._head)

     
    def __str__(self):
        tmp = self._head
        while tmp != None :
            print(f'{tmp._coef}x^{tmp._power}')
            tmp = tmp._next
    
    def insert(self, tup):
        pass
```

I tried making a while loop in the Poly *init* function and separating both the tuple numbers but I am not sure where to start on the Node class and am super confused, any help is appreciated and thankyou before hand.

**This is what output should look like:**

```
>>> p0 = Poly([(3,2), (1,0)])

>>> print(p0) 

>>> 1 + 3x^2

>>> p1 = Poly([(0,3),(4,5),(2,3),(3,4)])

>>> print(p1)

>>> 2x^3 + 3x^4 + 4x^5
```

Comment: The node class is fine, although you don't need `_next` as a parameter if you're not using it.  The `insert` function just needs to start at the beginning and insert the new node in its proper spot, in numerical order.  So if `_next` is not empty, and `_power`is greater than the new power, insert the new record here.

Comment: understood, but with the data being passed in being a list with tuples how would I create the Node in the first place that is what I am wondering? Like how would I tell python that the first number is a coefficient and the second number in the tuple is a power then cross-check if those powers are greater or not? I've tried a while loop but I cant get it to iterate and compare without an index error @TimRoberts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to describe the process.  Your inserter needs to scan through the list, looking for a node where the NEXT node has a higher power than the new node.  That's where you stitch in your new entry.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, coef, power, _next=None):
        self.coef = coef
        self.power = power
        self.next = _next
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.power:
            return f"{self.coef}x^{self.power}"
        return str(self.coef)

class Poly:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.head = None
        for i in lst:
            self.insert( i )
     
    def __str__(self):
        if not self.head:
            return "<Poly (none)>"
        nxt = self.head
        parts = []
        while nxt:
            parts.append(str(nxt))
            nxt = nxt.next
        return "<Poly " + (' + '.join(parts)) + ">"
    
    def insert(self, tup):
        node = Node(*tup)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
            return
        if self.head.power == node.power:
            self.head.coef += node.coef
            return
        # Loop until the NEXT node's power is larger than the new node.
        nxt = self.head
        while nxt.next and node.power > nxt.next.power:
            if node.power == nxt.power:
                nxt.coef += node.coef
                return
            nxt = nxt.next
        node.next = nxt.next
        nxt.next = node

p = Poly([(1,0),(2,2),(1,1),(3,4)])
print(p)
p = Poly([(0,3),(4,5),(2,3),(3,4)])
print(p)
```

Output:

```
<Poly 1 + 1x^1 + 2x^2 + 3x^4>
<Poly 2x^3 + 3x^4 + 4x^5>
```

The code becomes a little simpler if the "head" is actually a dummy node, so that `self.head.next`  has the first data node:

```
class Poly:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.head = Node(-1,-1)
        for i in lst:
            self.insert( i )
     
    def __str__(self):
        nxt = self.head.next
        parts = []
        while nxt:
            parts.append(str(nxt))
            nxt = nxt.next
        return "<Poly " + (' + '.join(parts)) + ">"
    

    def insert(self, tup):
        node = Node(*tup)
        # Loop until the NEXT node's power is larger than the new node.
        nxt = self.head
        while nxt.next and node.power > nxt.next.power:
            nxt = nxt.next
        if nxt.next and node.power == nxt.next.power:
            nxt.next.coef += node.coef
        else:
            node.next = nxt.next
            nxt.next = node
```

Comment: your code goes in reverse order how would I order it the way it is meant to be? for example, the lower powers go first and the higher powers go last. The output you show is not the output received from your code.

Comment: The output I showed in my first code is exactly the output of both code snippets.  The output appears in increasing order of the powers, which is wrong, but that's what you asked for.  If you're not seeing that result, then you copied my code incorrectly.

Comment: @TimeRoberts Sorry I meant to say if you have an instance where the tuples have the same power then the if statement meant to combine the two coefficient never happens and it just ends up skipping over it for example... ```[(1,0),(2,2),(1,1),(3,4),(3,2)]``` would end up with the result ```<Poly 1 + 1x^1 + 3x^2 + 2x^2 + 3x^4>``` instead of ```1 + 1x^1 + 5x^2 + 3x^4```

Comment: Ah, it was supposed to, but there was a bug.  Did you try to chase that down?  The second snippet now combines equal powers correctly.

Comment: yeah I chased that down could you explain the reason for the dummy node?

Comment: It just eliminates the need to treat the "head" as a special case.  Note that the loop is much simpler that way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to order things properly, I needed first to implement the insert function which looks at all scenarios where my `self._power` will be less than that of the tuple position 1 and instances where it's greater than or equivalent too.. after that I can loop through my list inside the `__init__` function and call on insert(tuple) with the tuples inside of the list to sort it.

in my `__str__` function:

a simple empty string, in the beginning, will suffice and while looping through the string I can keep adding to the empty string.